# For loop appends each new element to a list, but '\n' appears in place of commas

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

**EDIT:** Thank you all for the very helpful answers. Indeed, as suggested in the responses to this post, school_list did not in fact contain hundreds of list items, it contained only four. This didn't stop **school.text** from grabbing all the hundreds of places within those four elements that included the text of a school name.

**Original post:**
I'm trying to iterate over each school name on a web page containing hundreds of school names, and append each school name to a list called **list_of_names**. I am using the Python library Selenium to access the web page and locate the HTML element which contains the list of school names.

```
driver.get('https://www.illinoisreportcard.com/SearchResult.aspx?SearchText=$high%20school$&type=NAME#High-schools')
school_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('container.col-sm-12.col-md-12')

list_of_names = []

for school in school_list:
    try:
        name = school.text    
        print(name)   
        list_of_names.append(name)

    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```

As you can see below, where I've included the first three out of hundreds of results, the loop successfully prints the names of the schools plus grade information (which it has grabbed from each specified element of the HTML code).

```
ALLEN JUNIOR HIGH SCHOOL
(4 - 8)
LA MOILLE CUSD 303
(BUREAU)
LA MOILLE
CENTRALIA JR HIGH SCHOOL
(4 - 8)
```

The problem is that this line of code -- **list_of_names.append(name)** -- is *not* appending each of the school names as a list item surrounded by commas as separators, as I would have expected. Instead, it is appending each school name to one single list item that merely grows longer and longer. And in place of where commas should be, it is putting an '\n'.

Below is the first line of output of the command **print(list_of_names)**:

```
['ALLEN JUNIOR HIGH SCHOOL\n(4 - 8)\nLA MOILLE CUSD 303\n(BUREAU)\nLA MOILLE\nCENTRALIA JR HIGH SCHOOL\n(4 - 8)\nCENTRALIA SD 135\n(MARION)\
```

(I have tried versions of this on smaller lists of elements outside of HTML and thus without the need for the Selenium try/except code at the very bottom here, and it worked. But that still doesn't get me any closer to being able to deploy this code on the web page with the school names.)

What is going on? Why isn't this code appending each school name to **list_of_names** as individual items in a list?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I think you're being fooled by the output of `print(name)`.  It's a big string with embedded newline characters, and when you print it, the newlines make the text appear on different lines, but it's still one big giant string.

Comment: what do you see when you get the `len(school_list)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable "school_list" is not a list rather it's a string.
So essentially the for loop runs only once. "\n" is an escape sequence for "new line", which is why you are getting the output in the print statement

If you want the varaible "list_of_names" to have elements as show in your print statement you can replace the for loop with

```
for school in school_list.split('\n'):
```